# Can I dual boot from 2 Linux OS from 2 hard drives

Tags: dual-boot

I was given the impression that you can dual boot 2 Hard Drives with separate operating systems from GNU Grub as long as Ubuntu on 1st hard drive.  I was told you can do this with Boot-Repair Disk ??  When I load the DVD, it shows both systems Ubuntu, and CentOS 6.7. on their separate drives. However, the instructions on boot-repair are vague at best.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: UEFI or BIOS. BIOS straight forward, just install each systems boot loader to MBR of same drive, but always boot from one and run `sudo update-grub` With UEFI bit more complex, but also doable. Must be sure to install all systems in same UEFI or same BIOS boot mode if newer UEFI hardware.

Comment: What I need to know is how I get the CentOS MBR boot loader into the Ubuntu Grub ?? Not that simple to me, but I'm not a Guru yet..

Comment: You need to answer question and have you run `sudo update-grub`? What partitioning is CentOS using, standard ext4 or LVM? May be best to post the link from running Summary Report in Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

> I was given the impression that you can dual boot

You certainly can.

> 2 Hard Drives with separate operating systems from GNU Grub as long as Ubuntu on 1st hard drive.

That is not needed. "Windows" had that rule when using the old BIOS method. The new method uses a EFI partition so Microsoft also dropped that. Linux never had that rule.

> I was told you can do this with Boot-Repair Disk ?? When I load the DVD, it shows both systems Ubuntu, and CentOS 6.7. on their separate drives.

My experience is that Linux systems (not just Ubuntu) are always added to grub on installing that system. Nevertheless it does not do any harm if you do start it. It is pretty solid as far as my experience goes with this program.

> However, the instructions on boot-repair are vague at best.

Oh? Boot from a live dvd (for instance the one you installed Ubuntu from). You pick "try Ubuntu" and install boot-repair with the PPA that is in your link and start boot-repair.

Does not seem too difficult to me?

Comment: What I need to know is how I get the CentOS MBR boot loader into the  Ubuntu Grub ??  Not that simple to me, but I'm not a Guru yet..